# EnergyPlus/Modelica co-simulation error "asynchronous fmiDoStep is not supported"

Tags: modelica, dymola, fmi, energyplus

I have been trying to export a Modelica model from Dymola 2020 for a few weeks and continuously running into the following error message upon running co-simulation with EnergyPlus 9.2.

warning Model1 (): fmiInstantiateSlave: Callback function stepFinished != NULL but asynchronous fmiDoStep is not supported
warning Model1 (): fmiInstantiateSlave: timeout != 0 is not supported

I have followed [this forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/energyplus-fmu/rCqbZ4XzNOI/XR6osxRkAgAJ) but haven't been able to fix the problem.

Here is a list of troubleshooting steps we've done:

1. Imported the FMU we created into Dymola and it runs as expected - no
   issues with the FMU itself.
2. Ran MoistAir FMU example with the example idf - co-simulation runs without errors.
3. Ran MoistAir FMU example with our modified idf to ensure our EnergyPlus settings weren't the issue - co-simulation runs without errors.
4. Exported an FMU from the example moist air Modelica model from the Buildings library and ran with the example moist air idf in
   EnergyPlus - co-simulation does not run. Same asynchronous error.

Thinking there is a settings issue upon export from Dymola but at a loss for what to do next. Any help would be much appreciated.